# Find instance by name where query is any part of its name, Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In Java, the string search by its' substring goes like this:

```
String string = "Madam, I am Adam";
b = string.matches("(?i).*i am.*");
```

How to find an instance in Grails by name where query is any part of its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
DomainClass.findByNameIlike("%i am%")
```

That is a case insensitive search for any record with `name` containing "I am".  This is not an efficient way to query a database, so if your application will experience any kind of load, you should use it sparingly.

Edit: [Documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html)